# session variables set but return blank

Tags: php, session

I am trying to create a login flow but having problems setting the session variable,

when the user hits the page, i have a php document check to see if the user is logged in or if there are cookies set to re-log them in,

the code (simplified) to check is:

```
 <?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['uid'])) {
//logged in experience here
}   
else {

if (isset($_COOKIE['uname']) && isset($_COOKIE['key'])) {

                        //query database to ensure valid credentials

          if (<--valid-->){
          $_SESSION['uid'] = $uid; //set session variables
           $_SESSION['fname'] = $fname;
           var_dump($_SESSION);  //check to make sure variables set, this works
           //logged in experience
           }
           else {
                echo "error loggin in";
            }   

}

}


?>
```

on the first hit on the page, if session isnt set it goes to the cookies and then it sets the session variables. on the index page i print_r the session variables and i get the desired result, after navigating away from the page and then back using text links within the same subdomain the php is called again and this time the $_SESSION['uid'] is set however it is returned as blank as shown by the print_r.

So the problem is, somewhere between navigating away to a page that doesn't currently touch the session and then back the variable gets set to blank. I have also tested this by going to a page that does touch the session variables, it simply sets a session variable as a uniqid for me to track, and that variable is able to be recalled on the index page. Also, session_start() is called at the top of the index page as well,

the php on the index is simply

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'login_check.php';
print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

Comment: And where/how is the cookie (being) created? If no cookie is created, then the session won't be set, in turn not showing the session id/name on the next page. I see no cookie code in your question. All I'm seeing that is cookie-related, is checking to see if one is set.

Comment: where is the rest of the code?

Comment: this is just to check if the user is already logged in or a returning user, the cookies are set in the log in event

Comment: Just to make sure, do you have `session_start();` at the beginning of every page the user visits?

Comment: So, you're checking to see if two cookies are set, why two? *I hate golfing at night, the ball never lands in the (right) hole.*

Comment: @Ant What code are you wanting, right now im just trying to see if the user is logged in using session variables, if they aren't i check the cookies to see if they are a returning user. the handling of new users and users that have to manually log in is handled in a different area and that code is working in terms of setting the cookies and the session variables until the user navigates, that is where this code comes into play

Comment: @JohnMcMahon yes, every page the user touches session_start() is at the top. it will fail also if the page refreshes

Comment: @Fred-ii-I'm trying to mitigate tampering with cookies, two forms of validation (at least to me) seems more secure than one

Comment: Well, if "one" of the cookies isn't set, then it will fail. If that is the case, then you could try using an `OR` operator instead of an `AND` - I.e.: `if (isset($_COOKIE['uname']) || isset($_COOKIE['key'])) {` - Your code will also fail if the user is not accepting cookies or is not letting the browser load them, therefore you'd need a `Plan B`.

Comment: @Fred-ii-I'm sorry, I'm confused, could you please explain. These cookies are always set in pairs one should never be there without the other, so if one is set and the other is not that means by some means that they have been altered and then the user will have to re-login to verify identity. I am very new to this so please tell me where this logic is wrong

Comment: The logic is this: If a user decides to block cookies (which could be a likelihood), then the session id will never get set.

Comment: One thing is you don't need to add session_start() to the required file login_check.php

Comment: @Fred-ii-in this piece of code yes, however, the session variables are also set in the login event, so if the user blocks cookies they will just have to re-login every time they return to the site, correct?

Comment: I tend to agree. What conditional check are you using for `if (<--valid-->){` I was going to test this, but I don't know what to put in there, that's related to your code.

Comment: @Ant Ok, I did try that as well, I got the same result, I added it back in after reading a ton of articles about how it should be at the top of every page that access the session variables, however I will remove it from the require file

Comment: Ok, I just negated the `isset` to `!isset` to test and here are my results from a `print_r` Page one `array(2) { ["uid"]=> NULL ["fname"]=> NULL } Array ( [uid] => [fname] => )` and on page 2 `Array ( [uid] => [fname] => )` so had I a cookie in there, then it would have worked.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I run two queries, the one query for the uname should return the key and the key should return the uname, I have an if statement that cross checks the returns and sets a Boolean variable ($login_check) to true if the conditions are met. I set the variable to false at the begining of the validation and also in the else statement so the only way it can return true is if everything checks out

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, if the cookies are set it works, it sets the session variables and it is reflected on page1. I also tried setting the isset to !isset and it worked every time, but doing this requires the user have cookies enabled, if the don't they would never hit the logged in experience because i cant validate that they are logged in via the session variables which are set at the login event

Comment: I'm totally baffled. The only thing I can think of at this point is, instead of using `else { if (isset($_COOKIE['uname'])...` try doing `elseif (isset($_COOKIE['uname'])...` other than that, I don't know what else I could say that will help to figure this one out.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46476/discussion-between-cumminup07-and-fred-ii)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Spitballin

- **Remove any whitespace before** `<?php` in the file you include (which in this case is `login_check.php`)
- **Put this before** `session_start()` to keep the cookie from disappearing unexpectedly

  ```
  session_set_cookie_params(0);
  ```
- If that doesn't help, you should **try passing your `SID` (session ID) around your URLs** and see if that helps.  If you have `session.use_trans_sid` enabled in your **php.ini** file and your PHP installation was compiled with the configuration `--enable-trans-id` then the *SID* will be included in the URLs by default.  **[Check this page out for more information.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php)**
- **Remove the unnecessary** `session_start()` from the `login_check.php` since its already called on the originating page.

Comment: I got the same result with adding `session_set_cookie_params(0);` before the session_start();. there was no white space. reading up now on how to pass the SID around the URLs